# Get working directory in binary powershell module

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module

I'm writing a binary powershell module in C# and I can't seem to find out to get the current working directory from within a command.

My first thought was to do a simple `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` from the `System.IO` library but it only seems to give me the directory that powershell was launched in.

How can I get the current directory within a binary powershell module during a command execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your cmdlet derives from PSCmdlet, using `CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem").ProviderPath` should do the job nicely (untested).

Comment: In the event that I decide to derive from the base Cmdlet class, do you have any suggestions? I'm finding the PSCmdlet useful but a little bit restrictive.

Comment: You might hack up something with multiple classes, or maybe just cheat and call `Convert-Path .`. Probably ask a new question about that.